# Перевод кастомных подсказок

Tags: html, html5

Можно ли перевести вот эту кастомную подсказку на русский?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая библиотека? покажи код

Comment: Язык подсказки зависит от языка установленного в браузере по-умолчанию. Ее не нужно переводить.

Comment: Подробнее [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/required)

Answer (score 0):

Если допустить, что текст подсказки действительно кастомный и безальтернативно задан на английском языке, то можно добавить проверку языка интерфейса и написать кастомный русский перевод при желании.

Вот здесь по-русски про валидацию форм на стороне клиента с примерами кастомных сообщений об ошибках: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Условный пример проверки на пустоту с кастомной подсказкой:

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector('input');
const language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

nameInput.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
  if (nameInput.value === '') {
    if (language === 'ru') {
      nameInput.setCustomValidity('Скажи своё имя');
    } else if (language === 'en') {
      nameInput.setCustomValidity('Tell me your name');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Имя: </label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```